# Java script execution not waiting for python function call completion

Tags: javascript

I have a html page that is run in flask and uses python and javascript. On button click event, I have a Javascript function that calls a python method.

My requirement is that only after the python method execution is completed, another javascript function should be called. But it seems javascript is not waiting for python method completion. Following is the pseudo code.

Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks.

```js
 
 //This is the main JS function
 function JsMainFunc() {            
    JSFnThatCallsPythonFunc();
    //Function below should be executed only after the above function execution is completed
    JsFunc2();
}
function JSFnThatCallsPythonFunc(){
        //flask
        fetch('http://181.0.0.5:4000/PythonFunc1', {
            Func: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            body: "some response..")
        }
    }
function JsFunc2()
{
    //Some javascript
}
```

**EDIT**

Thanks for suggestint Then and Async approaches. I tried them and it only works if the methods doesnt have any python call. But if I have python call then the javascript execution is not waiting for the python method completion.

Example: The following works fine (it waits for the method completion before going to next method). it doesnot have python call. But if i introduce python call, it is not working.

```js
function main() {
  console.log("start");
            test1();
             console.log("end");
        }
        async function test1() {
          
            let myPromise = new Promise(function (myResolve, myReject) {
                setTimeout(function () { myResolve("Wait!"); }, 10000);
                console.log("I have waited here");
            });
            var s = await myPromise;
           

        }
```

Comment: `fetch(...).then(() => { callYourOtherFunctionHere() })`. This callback will execute after the request has finished (and long after the rest of your code finishes executing). Alternativly, look into async/await. You can do `async function JSFnThatCallsPythonFunc() { ... }` then do `await fetch(...)`

Comment: Thanks, I tried with the async function, It works fine if all are java script functions. But it doesnt work for method involving python call. it is not waiting for the python call to finish.

Comment: When using async/await, you just do this. `await fetch(...); console.log('this executes afterwards')`. You don't need to do `new Promise()` anywhere, that only useful for converting legacy callback-based APIs to promise-based ones, but fetch() is already promise-based.

Comment: I'm confused... Is your python call the fetch to flask or not? If it is and you want that to wait then there should be no problem clientside. If the fetch is doing something async serverside then you have shown us the wrong code that you are trying to wait for. And you would probably be leaving your connection open to long waiting for a separate process to finish.

Comment: Also, I am pretty sure that .then and await accomplish the same thing. I can't think of how they would be treated differently based on what you have explained so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //This is the main JS function
 function JsMainFunc() {            
    JSFnThatCallsPythonFunc().then(()=>{
    JsFunc2();
});
    //Function below should be executed only after the above function execution is completed
   
}
function JSFnThatCallsPythonFunc(){
        //flask
        return fetch('http://181.0.0.5:4000/PythonFunc1', {
            Func: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            body: "some response..")
        }
    }
function JsFunc2()
{
    //Some javascript
}
```

Place the JsFunc2 inside .then() which is a callback function for fulfill/reject case of a promise, that will only be called when "JSFnThatCallsPythonFunc" finishes executing.

I would suggest read about "event loop" and "promise" in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
async function JsMainFunc() {            
    await JSFnThatCallsPythonFunc();
    //Function below should be executed only after the above function execution is completed
    JsFunc2();
}
async function JSFnThatCallsPythonFunc(){
        //flask
        return fetch('http://181.0.0.5:4000/PythonFunc1', {
            Func: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            body: "some response..")
        }
    }
```